# How to send a certificate, with specified Provider, and to receive it on another side?

Tags: java, security, certificate, liferay, pkcs#12

How to send a certificate, which was created from keystore, with specified Provider, and to receive it on another side? I send it like a string in encoded by Base64 format, and cannot to convert it to Certificate, can anyone show how to transmit certificates? I have a file .p12, in Liferay system I should process verification of signed file using certificate, which must be uploaded from my applet to the server, and check sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to convert that certificate value into `Base64` format and then into `Hex` format then you will have to parse that data to other side. On the other side receive that data and then convert `Hex` to `Base64` then only you will have to prcess that value.

if you are not doing the same then you will have to face the problem of `BadPaddingException`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I convert certificate into Base64 format and send it, through the network, on the server side I receive it. I don't know how to convert string, certificate in base64, to Certificate object format

Comment: Certificate will contain data in binary format and you have to convert that value into `Base64` format, and then into `Hex` format. At the client side vice versa.